# Can jQuery return all elements where a specific child is empty?

Tags: jquery

Is there a jQuery selector to get table rows where the first anchor element has no text content?

```
$("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").has("a:first-of-type:empty");
```

**Edit:**

The `:first-of-type` in the above doesn't seem to work. These 3 lines all return the same result:

```
$("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").has("a:first-of-type:empty");
$("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").has("a:first-child:empty");
$("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").has("a:empty");
```

Full example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  alert($("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").has("a:first-of-type:empty").length);
  alert($("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").has("a:first-child:empty").length);
  alert($("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").has("a:empty").length);

  $("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").has("a:first-child:empty").each(function() {
    alert(this.id);
  });

});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  min-height: 20px;
  min-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tbl" style="width: 100%">
  <tbody>

    <tr class="item" id="one">
      <td><a href="/">ONE</a></td>
      <td><a></a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="alternatingitem" id="two">
      <td><a href="/">TWO</a></td>
      <td><a>TWO</a></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="item" id="three">
      <td><a href="/"></a></td>
      <td><a>THREE</a></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please show your complete code and demonstrate what specifically goes wrong. The selector you've shown works for me.

Comment: You're right. This does work. I don't know what's making mine not, but I just pulled a full code example and it works. I don't know what I cut out and I'm out of time so do feel free to close this.

Comment: Actually, today it doesn't work. It seems to hit where any A element is empty

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29401806/edit) and add the relevant code to help demonstrate and reproduce the issue.

Comment: You're right, the `first-of-type` selector does not do what you describe. It matches **siblings** of the same type and, since none of your `<a>` elements are siblings, they are all considered firsts of their type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty):

> The [`:empty` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) represents any element that has no children at all. Only element nodes and text (**including whitespace**) are considered. Comments or processing instructions do not affect whether an element is considered empty or not.

Your first anchor element may not contain children elements or text, but it is certainly possible that it contains whitespace. If it does, then the `:empty` pseudo-class *won't* select it.

You could check to see if the first anchor element has text *after* the whitespace has been trimmed:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx1nfevr/)

```
var $trWithEmptyAnchor = $("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").filter(function () {
    return !$.trim($(this).find('a:first-of-type').text());
});
console.log($trWithEmptyAnchor);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").has("a:first-child:empty");`

The :first-child pseudo class will get the first element.

Comment: It seems to be hitting on non empty elements

Comment: [Works just as well](http://jsfiddle.net/694xztd1/1/) with [`first-of-type`](https://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/). I'm not sure what the OP is asking.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't seen that pseudo-selector before. TIL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the [.map](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) jQuery method like this.

```
var allLinks = $("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem");

var emptyLinks = $.map(allLinks, function(item, index) {
   // item will reference any of your anchor elements
   // check if link has text
   if($(item).text() != "") {
      return item;
   }
});
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble achieving what you describe with a single chain of selectors.

The `first-of-type` selector matches siblings of the same type and, since none of your  elements are siblings, they are all considered firsts of their type. Essentially, you are selecting all rows that contain an empty `<a>`, which is not the desired functionality.

Below is a demonstration using your `first-of-type` selector. Code is minified for brevity.

```js
$("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").find("a:first-of-type:empty").addClass('highlight');
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid #000; width: 50%; } a { display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #00f; min-height: 20px; min-width: 40px; } .highlight { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<script src=https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js></script><p>Each <strong>a:first-of-child</strong> is highlighted in red:</p><table id=tbl style=width:100%><tbody><tr class=item id=one><td><a href="/">ONE</a><td><a></a><tr class=alternatingitem id=two><td><a href="/">TWO</a><td><a>TWO</a><tr class=item id=three><td><a href="/"></a><td><a>THREE</a></table>
```

---

However, I got it to work using [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). Given all the rows you selected, I'm iterating through each row to determine if its first `<a>` is empty.

```js
$("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").each(function(index,row) {
  $(row).find('a').first().filter(':empty').closest('tr').addClass('highlight');
});
```

```js
$("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").each(function(index,row) {
  $(row).find('a').first().filter(':empty').closest('tr').addClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #00f;
  min-height: 20px;
  min-width: 40px;
}
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl" style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>      
    <tr class="item" id="one">
      <td><a href="/">ONE</a></td>
      <td><a></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternatingitem" id="two">
      <td><a href="/">TWO</a></td>
      <td><a>TWO</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item" id="three">
      <td><a href="/"></a></td>
      <td><a>THREE</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### Edit:

Using [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is arguably more elegant (similar to the answer by [Josh Crozier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29402303/924299)):

```js
$("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").filter(function(index,row) {
  return $(row).find('a').first().is(':empty');
}).addClass('highlight');
```

```js
$("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").filter(function(index,row) {
  return $(row).find('a').first().is(':empty');
}).addClass('highlight');
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width:50%;
}
a {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #00f;
    min-height:20px;
    min-width:40px;
}
.highlight {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl" style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>      
    <tr class="item" id="one">
      <td><a href="/">ONE</a></td>
      <td><a></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternatingitem" id="two">
      <td><a href="/">TWO</a></td>
      <td><a>TWO</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item" id="three">
      <td><a href="/"></a></td>
      <td><a>THREE</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### Edit:

Or use [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/), as suggested by [Giorgos Manoltzas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29402040/924299):

```js
$("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").map(function(index,row) {
    if ($(row).find('a').first().is(':empty')) {
        return row;
    }
}).addClass('highlight');
```

```js
$("#tbl > tbody").children("tr.item, tr.alternatingitem").map(function(index,row) {
    if ($(row).find('a').first().is(':empty')) {
        return row;
    }
}).addClass('highlight');
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width:50%;
}
a {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #00f;
    min-height:20px;
    min-width:40px;
}
.highlight {
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl" style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>      
    <tr class="item" id="one">
      <td><a href="/">ONE</a></td>
      <td><a></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternatingitem" id="two">
      <td><a href="/">TWO</a></td>
      <td><a>TWO</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item" id="three">
      <td><a href="/"></a></td>
      <td><a>THREE</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```